# How can I update Zend Engine API? Ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-server

How can I update Zend Engine API?  I'm running PHP 5.2-5-3 ubuntu 4.1

I'm trying to run lampp, but I get this error for xdebug.

Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.1...
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220060519 which is installed, is outdated.

my php.ini has

zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Engine API `20090626` is for PHP 5.3. You need to build Xdebug with the PHP 5.2 version of `phpize`.